# I'am doing a server and client programming Server is a Windows form and client is a web application in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms, wcf

Error   1   Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Server side color.exe" to "bin\Debug\Server side color.exe". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\Server side color.exe' is denied. Server side color

Comment: most probably your "server" `bin\Debug\Server side color.exe` is running check on task manager

Comment: Thank you for your response but  in task manager its not running..-(

Answer (score -1):

Please run Visual Studio as Administrator. This is most likely the problem.

If that doesn't help please rename the "bin\debug\Server side color.exe" and try to build again.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response but i had runned in Administrator still its showing as a same message...:-(

Comment: Did you try to restart visual studio? Do you have muliple threads in your application? If that's the case make sure you close all of them when the application closes.